# Disabling TLS 1.0 and WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tls1.2

Need help on this below code in our WPF XAML application.

This below code (to read RTIConfig.xml)
is working when TLS 1.0 is enabled with https binding, but not working when TLS 1.0 is disabled with https binding.

```
public static string LoadRTIConfiguration()
{
    string rtiConfigDoc = string.Empty;
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/RTIConfig.xml", 
    UriKind.Absolute);
    // This info object is null. GetRemoteStream is returning null. Same 
    time not throwing any error.
    StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetRemoteStream(uri); 
    // Object null reference error getting here.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(info.Stream);
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    rtiConfigDoc = xdoc.ToString();
}
```

This code is working fine with http binding irrespective of TLS 1.0 enabled or disabled.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Sathis Kumar

Comment: what version of the .net framework are you using?

Comment: The fact that you use WPF should have no bearing on this.